# \rightdasharrow vs. \dashrightarrow

Tags: arrows, unicode-math, amssymb

`amsfonts` has `\dashrightarrow` (which is `\mathrel`), whereas `unicode-math` (with stix/xits) has `\rightdasharrow` (which is `\mathord`). Moreover, there are slight differences in the form of the symbol.

As far as my documents are concerned, I cannot imagine that I will ever use the two kinds of arrows simultaneously. I wonder whether there was any rationale for having created a new macro rather than simply replaced the definition of the old one.

By the way, should not the notation X⇢Y simply denote the set of partial maps from X to Y and thus ⇢ be a binary OPERATOR (rather than a relation)? The same goes for the normal (not dashed) arrow →.  Have there been any contexts in which → and ⇢ have been used as relations?

Crosspost: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=32988

Comment: Please don't crosspost, pick one or other forum and just ask once.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought it's fine, frankly. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293152 says it's fine in general and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=crosspost makes no provisions against crossposting either. If you disagree, I'm fine with everything (I'm even fine with me being blocked and banned forever from this site :-) ): feel free to flag my question and let the mods do their job of checking the rules.

Comment: I wouldn't enforce rules or flag, I just ask people not to cross post as it is asking people to waste effort answering questions if they are already answered elsewhere,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I might be missing something, perhaps, but you have not spoken about `\rightdasharrow` so far, which was a part of the question, have you?

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's `amsfonts` not `amssymb`

`amsfonts` package, if it detects `stix` is loaded, does

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\dabar@}{\mathord}{AMSa}{"39}
\xdef\dashrightarrow{\mathrel{\dabar@\dabar@
                          \mathchar"0\hexnumber@\symAMSa 4B}}%
\xdef\dashleftarrow{\mathrel{\mathchar"0\hexnumber@\symAMSa 4C\dabar@
                          \dabar@}}%
\global\let\dasharrow\dashrightarrow
```

so making both names `\dasharrow` and `\dashrightarrow` available with the same definition.

It's best to think of `\mathrel` as "spaced like =" rather than "is a mathematical relation" and arrows typically get rather more space than a typical binary relation like `+` so `\mathrel` even if that is mathematically dubious.

Comment: Thx! I've just changed amssymb to amsfonts in my question. I guess, xits is not detected (otherwise I wouldn't have noticed the difference). Also note that my question was not about `\dasharrow` vs. `\dashrightarrow` but rather `\rightdasharrow` vs. `\dashrightarrow`. Could you comment on `\rightdasharrow`?

Comment: @MdAyq yes Will and I need to try to better coordinate amsmath/unicode-math at some point, for historical reasons the current behaviour is partly because amsmath "detects" unicode-math and alters its behaviour and partly because unicodee-math detects amsmath and patches its definitions. There is an open issue on the unicode-math github to improve amsmath integration.....

Comment: I don't know, @DavidCarlisle...advocating that a user can choose math spacing based on preference??  You may get a visit from the mathrel-police.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am the mathrel-police, and you're nicked.

Comment: Yes sir, Mr. Inspector @DavidCarlisle.  The exception that makes the rule...I'll make a note of it.

Comment: The class `\mathrel` of the arrows in `amsfonts` is based on the class assigned to arrows in `plain.tex', e.g. `\mathcode`\^^Y="3221 % \rightarrow`.  It seems that the classes for `stix` weren't checked against that model.

Comment: Let me make up (notoriously dangerous and not encouraged) examples. The term A=B→C=D can be read as A=(B→C)=D, which introduces aliases A and D for the set of functions from B to C. Or you can read this term as (A=B)→(C=D), which makes A an alias for B and D an alias for C, and represents the set of functions from B to C. The first case is better written with spacing `A = B→C = D`, whereas the second case with spacing `A=B → C=D`. The same goes for the partial-functions symbol ⇢ (in lieue of →). In summary, it it not clear to me how the amounts of space around = and →/⇢ should be related.

Comment: What I do think is important is that in *f*: *A* → *B*, which intrdocues a function *f* with domain *A* and codomain *B*, the amount of space after the colon is larger than around the arrow. The same goes for *f*: *A* ⇢ *B*. So, it would probably be nice if `f\colon A\to B` and `f\colon A\dashrightarrow B` and `f\colon A\mathbin{\rightdasharrow} B` could satisfy this requirement by default. If they don't, a rationale would better be given on how to typeset *f*: *A* → *B* and *f*: *A* ⇢ *B* "correctly".